# Found 2 elements with non-unique id while working with gsp pages in grails

Tags: google-chrome, grails, gsp

I have created 2 radio buttons

```
<g:radio name="accountType" value="prepaid"/> PREPAID
<g:radio name="accountType" value="postpaid"/> POSTPAID
```

My chrome browser Version 67.0 started showing the following error

```
Found 2 elements with non-unique id
```

I found that id's must not be unique, but for radio buttons how come id's not to be unique.

Comment: Ids must be unique, the name may be shared (and should be for radios or groups of checkboxes).

Comment: Yes you are right  doelleri. Ids must be unique and the name can be shared. Issue fixed. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ids must be unique, but the name value can be shared

```
<g:radio name="accountType" id="prepaid" value="prepaid"/> PREPAID
<g:radio name="accountType" id="postpaid" value="postpaid"/> POSTPAID
```